# How to find number of ways one can move from $(0,0)$ to $(a,b)$ along the directed path?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In 2D space the point $(a,b)$ are said to be a lattice point if $a$, $b$ are integers. Two lattice points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are neighbours if they agree in one of the coordinates and differ in the other coordinate by $1$ . Every pair of neighbours is connected by a directed line with direction coinciding with the positive direction of the coordinate axis to which it is parallel. In how many ways one can move from $(0,0)$ to $(a,b)$ along the directed paths ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

If we pay close attention to the situation, we have to make $a$ moves in the right direction, and $b$ moves in the upward direction.

We will find ourselves on $(a,b)$ after making those moves, no matter in what order we make those moves.

Now, this problem has switched to: In how many ways can we arrange $a$ R's and $b$ U's.

For instance, if we have to find the number of ways one can move from $(0,0)$ to $(4,5)$, We will have to arrange $\underbrace{RRRR}_\text{4 times} \overbrace{UUUUU}^\text{5 times}$ in all possible ways, i.e., $\frac{9!}{4!5!}$

Now, generalising it for $(a,b)$, the number of ways = $\frac{(a+b)!}{a! \times b!}$